# Howto remove syslog completely from a yocto image based on systemd

Tags: yocto, systemd, syslog

I want to generate a Yocto image that uses systemd as the unique service to control my system logs. So I just want to use `journalctl` tool and don't want any reference to syslog at all.

To setup a systemd image I have setup my distro as this (as explained in the Yocto documentation):

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " systemd"
DISTRO_FEATURES_BACKFILL_CONSIDERED = "sysvinit"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_dev_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_init_manager = "systemd"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_initscripts = ""
```

However, the built image adds a rpm package called `sysklogd`, and the generated image runs some syslog related systemctl services:

```
- syslogd.service
- syslog.socket
```

I would like to generate and image with no reference to syslog at all. What should be the proper way to manage this issue?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
   VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_syslog = ""
```

in a .bb or .bbapend file. This will remove sysklogd package. 
Refer file /meta/recipes-extended/packagegroups/packagegroup-core-full-cmdline.bb where it is defined as

```
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_syslog ?= "sysklogd"
```

Comment: After adding VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_syslog = "" in my recipe image, the regenerated image still is built with `sysklogd` package. So this issue is not solved yet.

Comment: Generate bitbake -e <recipe-name> and see the value of VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_syslog .. Is it still "sysklogd"

Comment: It is VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_syslog="", but it generates an image with sysklogd. Doesn't have any sense...

Comment: I found this file: /lib/systemd/system/busybox-syslog.service. It seem my image is using busybox applet as syslog service... Im trying to remove busybox completely. Hope that helps. I will come back after that test.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed my issue. First of all I removed "busybox" from my custom image following the information explained in this link:

[Removing busybox completely from a Yocto generated image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830472/removing-busybox-completely-from-a-yocto-generated-image)

After removing busybox, defining this variable (as suggested on previous answers) worked as expected:

```
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_syslog = ""
```

Now the generated image doesn't contain any reference to syslog nor sysklogd. Thank you so much for all your support!! :-)