# Removing busybox completely from a Yocto generated image

Tags: yocto, syslog, busybox

I'm trying to build a yocto image without busybox and without any busybox
applet deployed.

I have tried that configuring my distro.conf file in this way:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = " busybox"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils = ""
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/base-utils = ""
```

Nonetheless, busybox binary and two related applets (syslog and udhcpc) are
installed in the generated image:

```
$ rpm -qa | grep busybox
busybox-syslog-1.24.1-r0.corei7_64
busybox-1.24.1-r0.corei7_64
busybox-udhcpc-1.24.1-r0.corei7_64
```

I have tried disabling syslog applet appending to my distro.conf file:

```
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_syslog ?= ""
```

But syslogd applet is still installed:

```
# ls -l /sbin/syslogd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Feb 15 14:03 /sbin/syslogd -> /bin/busybox.nosuid
```

Is there some way to remove busybox completely from the generated image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the right answer to my question. The trick to disable busybox completely is defining these variables in the distro.conf file:

```
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils = ""
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager = "shadow"
```

Last variable (login_manager) is only needed if you install "packagegroup-core-boot" in your custom image, such as in my case.

So, this question is solved. Thank you so much for all your support! :-)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I have to go as far as 

VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils = ""
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager = "shadow"
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils-hwclock = ""
VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_base-utils-syslog = ""
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/base-utils = ""

To completely remove it

Comment: That probably depends on the Yocto version you are working on. This was accepted as a good answer 3 years ago, but current Yocto version probably is not the same. Anyway, this is something that should be improved in the Yocto build process, this is too much complicated to just removing the busybox toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break apart packagegroup-core-boot:

1. make a copy of it;
2. remove busybox from it;
3. make your image inherit it instead of the original.

Comment: I commented from packagegroup-core-boot file this line:

    ## VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager ?= "busybox"

But now it complains with this error message:

    ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES '${VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager}'

It seems VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager needs a valid option. I have already tested with tinylogin but i get this error:

ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'tinylogin'

Is there some valid alternative? Where are defined?

Comment: @aicastell I highly recommend you creating another packagegroup; you could try "tinylogin", "login" and "shadow". Not sure which one would work nowadays.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your responses, Oleksandr. I have created a packagegroup in my custom layer (copying original content) and I have tested setting VIRTUAL-RUNTIME_login_manager variable with different values. Option "login" doesn't work, bitbake complains with Nothing RPROVIDES 'login'. The same with option "tinylogin". But with "shadow" option it works, the final image is build fine. However, busybox is into the image, and syslogd is still pointing to /bin/busybox.nosuid.